# HTTP PUT method in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I need to understand the PUT function by seeing examples with code,
I wonder if this is possible:

> Since most browsers do not support HTTP methods other than GET and POST, we mimic other methods (like PUT and DELETE) as follows. We send a normal POST request and add a parameter _method=PUT or _method=DELETE (take care of the underscore)

and how plz give me examples 
thanks in advance

Comment: I try to update a document on a server

Comment: I want to understand the method by examples

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588046/is-http-put-supported-in-j2me) tells me that PUT isn't part of the specification.

[Here is an example](http://www.acidum.de/2008/12/29/j2me-rest-client/) of a REST client implementing a `put`.

Comment: OK, if you understand it, please explain what it can do by general examples

Comment: Since most browsers do not support HTTP methods other than GET and POST, we mimic
other methods (like PUT and DELETE) as follows. We send a normal POST request and add a
parameter _method=PUT or _method=DELETE (take care of the underscore).